# iOS app - Apply background image object to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone help me understand how I apply a background image object to a UIView please?

I have created a background image which is a blurred version of a background and I would like to apply it to be the background of a uiView in the foreground which would ideally mask the background image.

I have the following code so far -

```
 _blurImage = [source stackBlur:50];
[_HPBlurView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[_blurImage]]];
```

I would like to apply the image object(_blurImage) to be the background image of _hpBlurView but i'm struggling to get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, you are using too many brackets. Here is a working version of your code :

```
_burImage = [source stackBlur:50];
_HPBlurImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:_blurImage];
```

I can't see what `stackBlur:50` returns. So start from the beginning. `colorWithPatternImag` takes `UIImage` as a parameter. So Start by adding a picture, any picture, to your application. Lets imagine that the image is called `image.png`. This is one way to do it:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
_HPBlurView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

This should help to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

Create an image and add to the background.:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youimage"];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

It's that.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure everything resizes properly, no matter rotation, device size and iOS version, I just set an UIImageView

```
//Create UIImageView
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; //or in your case you should use your _blurView
backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

//set it as a subview
[self.view addSubview:backgoundImageView]; //in your case, again, use _blurView

//just in case
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];
```